# Unable to run script in docker container

Tags: docker, shell

I am trying to run a shell script in docker container but when I launch the container, runtime is unable to find the script.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV URL=http://localhost:8080
ENV ORG="name1"
ENV ADMIN="john"

ADD data-prep.sh /usr/local/data-prep.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/data-prep.sh

RUN ls -l /usr/local/*.sh

CMD ["/user/local/data-prep.sh", URL, ORG, ADMIN]
```

and when i run the container, I get following error

```
    /bin/sh: 1: [/user/local/data-prep.sh,: not found
```

Any idea what is wrong with my Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CMD` is looking into wrong path, it should be `usr` not `user`.

```
CMD ["/usr/local/data-prep.sh", URL, ORG, ADMIN]
```

Also if you want to consume `ENV`, you need to change `CMD` as variable not expending in `CMD`.

```
CMD ["sh","-c","/usr/local/data-prep.sh $URL $ORG $ADMIN"]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, i get the same error even after correcting the typo. 

/bin/sh: 1: [/usr/local/data-prep.sh,: not found

Comment: Answer updated, it because of the `ENV` that you are trying to access.

Comment: After making suggested changes, i get this: /bin/sh: 1: [sh,: not found

Comment: I just verfied on my localsystem and it seems working fine, did you rebuild the docker image? or you can replace with `CMD ["/bin/bash","-c","/usr/local/data-prep.sh $URL $ORG $ADMIN"]`

Comment: also `data-prep.sh` is it start with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: yes, I rebuilt the image and data-prep.sh starts with #!/bin/bash

Comment: Tried with CMD ["/bin/bash","-c","/usr/local/data-prep.sh $URL $ORG $ADMIN"] as well, now it complains for /bin/bash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218426/discussion-between-adiii-and-balkrishan-nagpal).